# Excel if cell contain "-" near number then move

Tags: vba, excel

What I need to do is to basically write lessons number. There are 3 colomns.
[image]

The second column is running by a custom formula called LessonsLeft done by someone from my second thread on stackoverflow and it is

```
    Function LessonsLeft(rng As Range) As String
If rng.Count > 1 Then Exit Function
Dim spltStr() As String
Dim i As Long
spltStr = Split(rng.Value, ",")
LessonsLeft = ",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,"
For i = LBound(spltStr) To UBound(spltStr)
    LessonsLeft = Replace(LessonsLeft, "," & spltStr(i) & ",", ",")
Next i
LessonsLeft = Mid(LessonsLeft, 2, Len(LessonsLeft) - 2)
End Function
```

What I need to do is to add another, third colomn which is for lessons that my students  did their first attempt but they couldnt pass exam.

How i want the data to be there, is to write for exemple a "-" or "+" near a number in first column so the number will move to third column.

How can it be done ?

Comment: What I mean is that for exemple if i write in first column "5-", the 5 will appear in third one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this function

```
Function LessonsAttemptedButNotDone(rng As Range) As String
    If rng.Count > 1 Then Exit Function
    Dim spltStr() As String, lessonDone As String
    Dim i As Long

    spltStr = Split(rng.Value, ",")
    For i = LBound(spltStr) To UBound(spltStr)
        lessonDone = spltStr(i)
        If Right(lessonDone, 1) = "-" Then
            lessonDone = Left(lessonDone, Len(lessonDone) - 1)
            LessonsAttemptedButNotDone = LessonsAttemptedButNotDone & lessonDone & ","
        End If
    Next
    If LessonsAttemptedButNotDone <> "" Then LessonsAttemptedButNotDone = Left(LessonsAttemptedButNotDone, Len(LessonsAttemptedButNotDone) - 1)
End Function
```

Comment: This is doing the job. Thanks